# C# PLINQ WithDegreeOfParallelism always load 100% CPUs

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, plinq

I have changed my LINQ query in C# .NET 4.7, introducing AsParallel() and WithDegreeOfParallelism().

My CPU is an i7 with 4 cores and 8 logic processors.
With any value in WithDegreeOfParallelism (from 2 to 8), I have always all process at 100% of use, when query is executed. Why?
I expect that decrement the degree, also CPU load will decrement.

My code Example:

```
var tem = from cF in cFiles.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
    join cFMI in cFilesByMastersIds.AsParallel() on cF.MasterId equals cFMI.MasterId
    where cF.FileRev.Label != cFMI.FileRev.Label
        select new { cF, FileRevMaster = cFMI.FileRev.Label };
```

Screen of task manager:
[image]

Comment: ...but you're joining a DOP constrained "Parallel" with an unconstrained one...

Comment: You don't need the second `AsParallel()`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if I revome the second AsParallel() I have the warning:the second datasource must be the type ParallelQuery; use the AsParallel() extension to convert the right datasource

Comment: @spender sorry I don't understand, can you explain in depth?

Comment: Beyond increased CPU usage do you get any performance improvement out of this? My impression is that joining enumerables is not a parallel-friendly operation. Not all computations can be parallelized.

Comment: Set the DOP in both inputs but beware: `AsParallel()` or `Parallel.ForXYZ` work by partitioning the input and using one worker task per core to process each partition. Joins require special handling to avoid M*N comparisons. Both the sequential and parallel LINQ operators will try to take advantage of [ordering in the *left* source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Parallel/QueryOperators/Binary/JoinQueryOperator.cs,5763c8fab7676d58) otherwise they'll hash the inputs to speed up comparisons

Comment: Both ordering and hashing benefit from parallelization. Setting a DOP of 1 on both sides though may result in slower execution than a sequential JOIN. If the left source is already ordered though you can use [AsOrdered()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered?view=netframework-4.8) to tell PLINQ that this source is already ordered. Otherwise it will use hashing.

Comment: Database servers use statistics and knowledge of the schema and indexes to decide whether they should use parallelism, whether to order the data before joining or use hash joins. With PLINQ you'll have to do that yourself and decide which source should go left or right, whether to order before joining etc

Comment: BTW what is `cFilesByMastersIds`? If it was a list of IDs I would expect it to be a lot smaller than the other source.

Comment: `cFiles` and `cFilesByMastersIds` have same dimension, near to 30K records. If I use Parallel I have a burst of 50% time reduction in execution, but 100% CPU usage.